# Do i have perfect pitch , if i corrected my friend about her high note

Tags: absolute-pitch

My friend was having trouble with a high note , I checked the song out and sang the song almost instantly and I also hit the high note , a week or 2 later she randomly started going higher in pitch and then stopped , and I told her she was quite close to hitting the note in the song , she was quite surprised because she thought it was very high , I have very limited knowledge on musical theory , does this mean I have perfect pitch

Comment: Absolutely impossible to say either way from this, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Merely knowing a note is high or low isn't enough. Those with absolute pitch have the propensity to identify just about any sound - from a sung note to a car's exhaust - and to be able to label that with a pitch. "That hum from the fan is a B♭". And it will be! If you have reference from a musical instrument, or tuner, and you correctly identify some notes, then there's proof.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you've described here is generally known as relative pitch, where you can hear and recognize whether a note is on key according to the parent scale of the song. This can usually be learned by ear training and scale studies and is invaluable to those of us who perform music. I do not have absolute pitch, but I've been told it can actually make those who have it uncomfortable to hear a song that's a little off key.