# How do I determine I have perfect pitch

Tags: absolute-pitch

I was recently told about this and I was wondering do I have perfect pitch or some variation of it.
I have no prior musical experience in any shape or form yet despite this I have always been able to replicate any piece of music or sound I hear perfectly either through humming it singing it or whistling it, notice the difference and changes in pitch and notes played, call out the amount of notes played in x amount of seconds etc. What recently also occurred to me after messing around with a keyboard is that after fiddling around with the keys for a while, I was able to match notes heard in everyday sounds to the sound that was made from one of the keys I fiddled around with, albeit I don't know the name of the notes or specific key.

Comment: The answers here may help you decide: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/97870/do-i-have-perfect-pitch-if-i-corrected-my-friend-about-her-high-note

Comment: A test is proposed here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104307/can-someone-have-perfect-relative-pitch-without-knowing-it/104310#104310

Comment: See also [Do I have perfect pitch or good pitch memory?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81719/do-i-have-perfect-pitch-or-good-pitch-memory) -- [Do I have perfect pitch?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/56177/do-i-have-perfect-pitch) -- and [Do I have perfect pitch](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37908/do-i-have-perfect-pitch)

Answer (score 1):

A simple test - play one specific note on that keyboard, sing it. Its name doesn't matter, but remember where it is. For the next few days, sing that particular note, then check your accuracy by playing that note. Then choose a different note, and repeat. If you are accurate, there's a good chance you have perfect (absolute) pitch.

Not being a musician, or not knowing what a pitch is called, should not be a criterion negating absolute pitch - although it's more usual for someone involved in music to at least be aware that they possess absolute pitch, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Huh, turns out I was accurate in all the times I did that since this reply was posted. Epic.